# How to switch multi-tool modes and reload the Bolt Caster?

Tags: no-mans-sky

On PS4 - I got to a factory and the game told me to craft a Bolt Caster upgrade for my multi-tool so I can break in, which I did.

I now have 48 rounds in clip, and 352 spare. I start shooting at the door, and empty the clip. The game is telling me to reload, but not how. It displays 0/352.

I found I could recharge the Bolt Caster with plutonium and the clip would reload, but this is awkward.

Then, after successfully getting the antimatter blueprint, I decide to farm some resources. The Bolt Caster seemed to do nothing. I couldn't find a way to switch, so I dismantled the Bolt Caster upgrade.

Is there an easier way to do this on the PS4?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the controls screen indicates, press triangle to switch weapon modes (in your spaceship too) and square to reload.

Comment: okay - i'll try again - but I did mash buttons to try and get this to work last night... and I forgot there is a control map in the options menu.

Comment: Also it's [R] on PC as it is for most shooters.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill And X to switch modes on pc

Comment: hmm - the problem seems to be I wasn't holding the square or triangle for long enough - would have been nice to see some kind of feedback in the hud that I needed to hold longer.

Comment: Yes, the designers did an awful job with the PS4 controls, especially in the menus.